# iSCSI on Windows Server 2003 data not showing on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi

I have a Western Digital My Cloud EX2 drive with 4TB RAID 1.  I created a iSCSI Target on the disk and set up 2 initiators.  One on Windows Server 2003 and one on Windows Server 2012 R1.  My purpose it to have the 2 servers share the same drive yet make it look like a local disk.  That's the reason for not creating a mapped drive.  If I place files to the drive from the Windows 2003 Server, I'm not able to view it in the 2012 Server (and vice versa).  How can I make this work?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Cluster role or not (for what role write there) ? If not, you gonna corrupt your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STOP WHAT YOU'RE DOING!!

If you go down this road, you're going to have file corruption and likely data loss.

You can't "share" an iSCSI volume across two servers like this, except in very specific situations. Sadly none of cases will work for you since you've got a Windows 2003 server. I won't get in to the discussion of why you still have something like that around.

[iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI) is a block based protocol and as such each server expects to have exclusive access to the volume and filesystem.

In Windows Clustering (what Yagmoth555 has asked about) the two servers work together to make sure only one ever uses the disk.

Again, there are exceptions to this rule, but they involve having more recent OSs (at least Windows Server 2008 R2) and even then, only in certain use cases.